# Пустые данные html страницы

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Использую `Simple Html Dom`. Например, [вот эта страница](https://2gis.ru/barnaul/search/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9?queryState=zoom%2F11):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь найти `span` с соответствующим классом, в ответ получаю ничего.
Использую код:

```
<?php
include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$address = "https://2gis.ru/barnaul/search/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9";

$html->load_file($address);    

echo $html->find('.searchBar__mediaTabTextDescription', 0);
```

Comment: Более подробно опишите, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Там адово поклонение AJAX, в загружаемой странице нет многих полей, в т. ч. и искомого Вами. Среди каши сложно найти куда именно запрос для извлечения организаций уходит, поищите через инстпектор запросов, наверное.

Comment: API 2GIS не пробовали подключить и не страдать ерундой?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дорогой друг, дело в том, что мы используем изоморфный js-фреймворк и отдаём с сервера только то, что может понадобиться seo. В твоём случае ты пытаешься парсить часть медийной карточки, которую мы инитим уже на клиенте. Спасибо, что небезразличен!

Если нужно доехать (информация), а не шашечки (попарсить сайт и получить бан), то можно использовать такие варианты:

1. [Выгрузка из справочника](http://content.2gis.ru/sample/)
2. [2GIS API](http://api.2gis.ru/)